# Ways to overcome the file overwriting with Matplotlib

Tags: python, bash, matplotlib

I have a python code and a bash script for it to apply the python script onto all files in directory. The output is made with the help of Matplotlib, so I get graphics for every file in the directory (at least I want to).

My problem is that Matplotlib overwrites the file, so instead of 10 separate diagrams I get only one that was overwritten multiple times. How do I solve this problem? They all obviously have to have different file names...

So far I have been using

```
             plt.savefig(Output_path + "/NewDiagram.png")
```

Cannot really find any other solution. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you post more code? So your problem is that you can't create multiple file names?

Comment: Yes, the bash script iterates over files in a directory and applies the python code on each file. But the diagram gets overwritten with every execution

Comment: `plt.savefig(Output_path + "/NewDiagram-{}.png".format(file_number)` where `file_number` is the file you process. Post the code for better answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add some unique prefix to the png file name. for example you can add current unix time to the file name:

```
import time
plt.savefig(Output_path + "/NewDiagram_%s.png" % (time.time()))
```

Comment: There is a problem here. You will not know for which file the diagram belongs to according to the question as there are multiple files

Comment: I get name 'Time' not defined

Comment: 'Time' has upper case t, you must use 'time' maybe! @ta4le

Comment: that is autocorrection, 'time' is not defined still